# Ways to speed up code with multiple IF statements

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working on this code all day and have finally gotten everything to work perfectly. The only problem, is that the code does run pretty slow. Considering that it will be used on a workbook with thousands of rows I would like to change that. I am extremely new to vba so there is probably stuff in here that is wrong or seems like a bad shortcut. I think I added a couple of ways that could speed it up but i didnt know if anything else could be done.

```
 Sub Degree_Workboook_Names_major1()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False

'Inserts a new column after column H named department names
 range("I1").EntireColumn.Insert
 range("I1").Value = "DeptName"


 Dim abbrRange As range              'range to hold the columns with the department names
 Set abbrRange = range("H:H")

'Writes the department name in the the department name column next to the associated abbr

 For Each cell In abbrRange


            If cell.Value = "ACC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Accounting"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ACS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Adolescent, Career and Special Education"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AES" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Animal and Equine Science"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AGR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Agricultural Science"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AHS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Applied Health Sciences"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AHT" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Veterinary Technology and Pre-Veterinary Medicine"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "Art" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Art and Design"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "BIO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Biology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "BPA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Management, Marketing and Business Administration"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CCD" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Center for Communication Disorders"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CEAO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Bachelor of Integrated Studies Program"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CHE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Chemistry"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CLH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Community Leadership and Human Services"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "COM" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Organizational Communication"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Computer Science and Information Systems"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ECO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Economics and Finance"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ELE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Early Childhood and Elementary Education"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ENPH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of English and Philosophy"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ELSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Educational Studies, Leadership and Counseling"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "GSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Geosciences"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "HFA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Liberal Arts"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "HIS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of History"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "INDC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Institute of Engineering"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "IOE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Institute of Engineering"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "JMC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Journalism and Mass Communications"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MAT" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Mathematics and Statistics"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MLA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Modern Languages"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MMB" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Management, Marketing and Business Administration"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MSP" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Military Science Program"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MUS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Music"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "NUR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Nursing"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "OSH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Occupational Safety and Health"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "POL" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Political Science and Sociology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "PSY" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Psychology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "THR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Theatre"
            End If

 Next



 'Inserts a new column after column H named department names
range("M1").EntireColumn.Insert
range("M1").Value = "DeptName"


'Dim abbrRange As range              'range to hold the columns with the   dpeartment names
Set abbrRange = range("L:L")

'Writes the department name in the the department name column next to the associated abbr

For Each cell In abbrRange


            If cell.Value = "ACC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Accounting"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ACS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Adolescent, Career and Special Education"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AES" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Animal and Equine Science"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AGR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Agricultural Science"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AHS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Applied Health Sciences"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "AHT" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Veterinary Technology and Pre-Veterinary Medicine"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "Art" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Art and Design"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "BIO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Biology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "BPA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Management, Marketing and Business Administration"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CCD" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Center for Communication Disorders"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CEAO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Bachelor of Integrated Studies Program"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CHE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Chemistry"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CLH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Community Leadership and Human Services"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "COM" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Organizational Communication"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "CSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Computer Science and Information Systems"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ECO" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Economics and Finance"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ELE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Early Childhood and Elementary Education"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ENPH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of English and Philosophy"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "ELSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Educational Studies, Leadership and Counseling"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "GSC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Geosciences"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "HFA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Liberal Arts"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "HIS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of History"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "INDC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Institute of Engineering"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "IOE" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Institute of Engineering"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "JMC" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Journalism and Mass Communications"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MAT" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Mathematics and Statistics"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MLA" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Modern Languages"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MMB" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Management, Marketing and Business Administration"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MSP" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Military Science Program"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "MUS" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Music"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "NUR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Nursing"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "OSH" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Occupational Safety and Health"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "POL" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Political Science and Sociology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "PSY" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Psychology"
            End If

            If cell.Value = "THR" Then
            cell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "Department of Theatre"
            End If

Next



range("I:I").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
range("M:M").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Comment: The reason your code is slow is b/c you keep constantly activating the worksheet directly. This is something you should avoid doing at all costs. Instead you could try thiscell.value = this. Directly assigning a value is INF more efficient. Remember - try to interact wih the excel object(s) directly as little as humanly possible

Comment: 3 main issues here: You loop over an entire column (1000000 cells) - use .End(xlUp) to locate the used range , you loop over cells - use a Variant Array instead , you use Select/Activate - use variables instead

Comment: cell.Offset(0,1).Value = "" is how you would directly apply value to a cell instead of activatin it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, I would prefer arrays, though Dictionary is the good option.
An example code would be like this....

```
Sub Degree_Workbook_Names_major1()
Dim abbrRange As Range
Dim Abbr, Dept()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Columns("I").Insert
Range("I1").Value = "DeptName"

Set abbrRange = Range("H2:H" & lr)
Abbr = abbrRange.Value
ReDim Dept(1 To lr)

For i = 1 To UBound(Abbr, 1)
    Select Case UCase(Abbr(i, 1))
        Case "ACC"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Accounting"
        Case "ACS"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Adolescent, Career and Special Education"
        Case "AES"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Animal and Equine Science"
        Case "AGR"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Department of Agricultural Science"
        Case "AHS"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Applied Health Science"
        Case "AHT"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Veterinary Technology and Pre-Veterinary Medicine"
        Case "ART"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Art and Design"
        Case "BIO"
            Dept(i) = "Department of Biology"
        'similarly add rest of the Abbreviations with Case statement and set the array Dept as shown above
    End Select
Next i
Range("I2").Resize(UBound(Dept)).Value = Application.Transpose(Dept)

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I really like the way you did it. The only problem I have is that column H has empty cells in it so I can't do the ``End.(xlUp)`` to find the last row. I know that columns A-G will have data in every row so would I be able to find the last row of one of those columns and offset it to to be column H?

Comment: In that case you only need to replace the line lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row WITH lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Thank you. @sktneer I just have one last question. As it turn out some of the names in the column need to be renamed if a value in column E is = to "BS" so could I write something like `Case "INDC"`
          `If` ` `Range("E1:E").Value = "BS" Then`
           `Dept(i) = "IOE"`

Answer (score 5):

Every single condition is executing every time, irrespective of `Cell.Value`.

Working with cells and ranges in a loop is certainly the single slowest thing you can do in Excel VBA, but doing it for a dozen of conditions when you only need to check a single one... is even slower.

Replace it with `If...Else If...Else If... ...End If`, or use a `Select Case` block:

```
Select Case cell.Value
    Case "ABC"
       'handle 'ABC'
    Case "DEF"
       'handle 'DEF'
    '...
    Case "XYZ"
       'handle 'XYZ'
    Case Else
       'handle default
End Select
```

But that still makes "XYZ" be evaluated only after every single other case has been evaluated.

A better alternative could be to setup a `Dictionary`. Reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library.

```
Static map As Scripting.Dictionary
If map Is Nothing Then
    Set map = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With map
        .Add "ACC", "Department of Accounting"
        .Add "ACS", "Department of Adolescent, Career and Special Education"
        '...add every possible ABC -> Description map
    End With
End If

cell.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
If map.Exists(cell.Value) Then ActiveCell.Value = map(cell.Value)
```

The `Static` dictionary will only be populated the first time the procedure runs. Then the `ActiveCell.Value` is simply fetched with a lightning-fast dictionary lookup.

Now, that's likely *still* going to be very slow. You don't need 2 loops: iterate *rows* (only the ones you *know* you need to check), and then do `H` and `L` in one single pass. Just that is slicing execution time by half. Avoid `.Activate`, too; you don't need to work off `ActiveCell` at all.

Comment: I will try to do this @Mat'sMug. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 your code will likely still be terribly slow. Try to avoid `.Activate` whenever possible.

Comment: so for the dictionary, is the ``cell.activate`` part putting the corresponding department name in the cell next to the cell with the abbreviation?

Comment: `cell.Activate` only allows you to assign `ActiveCell.Value`. Instead, assign `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` directly, without activating anything.

Comment: Ok I got you, well thank you for all of your help. I'm going to try and re-write this to work with the dictionary since it seems it will definitely be more efficient and helpful in the future.

Comment: @Mat'sMug there arent enough typos in your post :P

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use switch-case statements instead of if statement. See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_switch_statement.htm

The problem on your code is, that all if statements are getting checked even if the first one is applicable.

Comment: Actually select case would be even slower in some instances. The real problem is the direct interaction with the worksheet objects

Comment: I don't think select case would be slower in this case. But you're right the direct interaction with the worksheet object could be the problem.

Comment: Could you help me with the syntax for the thiscell.value I tried writing it like this        'If cell.Value = "ACC" Then '
'                    ThisCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Department of Accounting" '
'                    End If   '   but got an error

Comment: Code must be written down in backticks `` `Here is code`

Comment: Could you help me with the syntax for the thiscell.value I tried writing it like this ``If cell.Value = "ACC" Then  ThisCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Department of Accounting"  End If  `` but got an error

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 - `If cell.Value = "ACC" Then` `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Department of Accounting"` `End If`