# How to reduce the number of if-else statements (e.g. avoid hardcoding values)?

Tags: vb.net, hardcoded

How to do this without hardcoding every Jar version?
So, in every `ElseIf`, it checks the version, if it's (for example 1.2.5), then download the software accordingly, to the path selected by the user + \ + *type* + _ + *version* + .jar.  The problem is that there are more versions (more than 30 I think) and I don't want to hardcode all of them.

```
If JarVer = "1.2.1" Or JarVer = "1.2.2" Or JarVer = "1.2.3" Or JarVer = "1.2.4" Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
                "https://assets.minecraft.net/1_2/minecraft_server.jar",
                Path + "\" + SW + "_" + JarVer + ".jar")
            ElseIf JarVer = "1.2.5" Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
                "https://assets.minecraft.net/1_2_5/minecraft_server.jar",
                Path + "\" + SW + "_" + JarVer + ".jar")
            ElseIf JarVer = "1.3.1" Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
                "https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/d8321edc9470e56b8ad5c67bbd16beba25843336/server.jar",
                Path + "\" + SW + "_" + JarVer + ".jar")
            ElseIf JarVer = "1.3.2" Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
                "https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/82563ce498bfc1fc8a2cb5bf236f7da86a390646/server.jar",
                Path + "\" + SW + "_" + JarVer + ".jar")
            ElseIf JarVer = "1.4.2" Then
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
                "https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/3de2ae6c488135596e073a9589842800c9f53bfe/server.jar",
                Path + "\" + SW + "_" + JarVer + ".jar")
            ...
```

Comment: You need to define the relationship between `JarVer` and the download path *somewhere*. If you don't want it hardcode, you could write it into an Excel sheet or a textfile and read that to figure out the Download

Comment: Also maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149604/ways-to-speed-up-code-with-multiple-if-statements

Comment: Note that in general lots of if-elses is sometimes appropriate. Alternatively, you can use switch statements or a dictionary, in some cases. These are language-agnostic concepts that apply to most programming languages.

Answer (score -1):

They have to be hardcoded somewhere unless you have a consistent pattern.

I would consider putting the list in a data table or dictionary, then looking up the url from the version.